# Saving APEX updateable report values into Excel

Tags: database, oracle, excel, export-to-excel, oracle-apex

I'm using an APEX report which has some updateable columns and change based on user input using a javascript function (mimicking a spreadsheet with formulas). All of this works fine, but the problem I am running into is that when I use the built in export to excel function, it doesn't use the updated values (instead, it uses the original values grabbed from a database). I'm wondering how I can either save these updated values or find a way to export them in a different way. Also, it might be important to note that APEX 3.0 is used (not the latest version).

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit the values back to the database to use the standard export  (or to save the changes).  If you are in a form this should be possible, however I'm not quiet sure what a report with updatebale columns is...are you in a tabular form?  Or is this a customised screen?

Comment: Sorry, it is a tabular form. The problem is that these values shouldn't be written to the database as they are only for test purposes, not for actual changes. I'm guessing though that the way you explained the standard export means that I will have to implement my own export if I want the user entered data to appear on the spreadsheet. Thanks for the help!